# Yii2 Auto Input when Selecting Certain Item from dropDownList

Tags: php, autocomplete, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I had 2 input in my form named Kode Soal and Jenis Soal. I want to make the Kode Soal input auto-filled when I selected certain item from Jenis Soal dropDownList. I know that I need to include an if case here, but where I should include it? This case is not about calling item from the database, I want just to autofill the input before I submit it.

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>

<div class="soal-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <!-- THIS IS THE DROP DOWN LIST -->
    <?= $form->field($model, 'jenis_soal')->dropDownList([
        'pedagogik' => 'Kompetensi Pedagogik',
        'profesional' => 'Kompetensi Profesional',
        'kepribadian' => 'Aspek Kepribadian',
        'sosial' => 'Aspek Sosial'
    ], ['id' => 'jenisSoalId'])?>


    <!-- WHEN I SELECT E.G. Kompetensi Pedagogik, it should automatically filled "PED" -->

    <?php
    if(!empty($model->jenis_soal) && $model->jenis_soal == 'pedagogik') {
        $model->kode_soal = 'PED';
    }elseif($model->jenis_soal == 'profesional'){
        $model->kode_soal == 'PROF';
    }elseif($model->jenis_soal == 'kepribadian') {
        $model->kode_soal == 'KEP';
    }elseif($model->jenis_soal == 'sosial') {
        $model->kode_soal == 'SOS';
    }
    ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'kode_soal')->dropDownList([
        'PED' => 'PED', 'PROF' => 'PROF', 'KEP' => 'KEP', 'SOS' => 'SOS'
    ], ['id' => 'kodeSoalId'])?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'soal')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>


    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>

<script>
$("#jenisSoalId").change(function() {
     if($("#jenisSoalId").val() == 'pedagogik') {
         $("#kodeSoalId").val("PED");
     }
     if($("#jenisSoalId").val() == 'profesional') {
         $("#kodeSoalId").val("PROF");
     }
     if($("#jenisSoalId").val() == 'kepribadian') {
         $("#kodeSoalId").val("KEP");
     }
     if($("#jenisSoalId").val() == 'sosial') {
         $("#kodeSoalId").val("SOS");
     }
});
</script>
```

When user select "Kompetensi Pedagogik" in Jenis Soal, the Kode Soal input should autofilled with text "PED", else, if "Kompetensi Profesional" is selected, the Kode Soal filled with "PROF", hence, "Kompetensi Kepribadian" is "KEP" and "Kompetensi Sosial" is "SOS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <!-- THIS IS THE DROP DOWN LIST -->

    <?= $form->field($model, 'jenis_soal')->dropDownList([
        'pedagogik' => 'Kompetensi Pedagogik', 
        'profesional' => 'Kompetensi Profesional', 
        'kepribadian' => 'Aspek Kepribadian', 
        'sosial' => 'Aspek Sosial'
    ], ['id' => 'jenisSolaId']) ?>

    <!-- WHEN I SELECT E.G. Kompetensi Pedagogik, it should automatically filled "PED" here -->
    <?php if (!empty($model->jenis_soal) && $model->jenis_soal == 'pedagogik') : ?>
         <?php $model->kode_soal = 'PED'; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'kode_soal')->textInput(['id' => 'kodeSolaId', 'maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'soal')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

<script>
     $("#jenisSolaId").change(function() {
         if($("#jenisSolaId").val() == 'pedagogik') {
             $("#kodeSolaId").val("PED");
         }
     });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the function of JS Script underneath? I think that we need to include <script> tag before it. I got unexpected end of file when implementing the code.

Comment: It still not working, I edited the code now I include entire file. Mind that PED, PROF, KEP and SOS is not included in any tables beforehand. I intend to make the jenis_soal field filled with either PED, PROF, KEP, and SOS.